# Where is the FAQ about Moderator Tools?

Tags: support

Call me a dummy, but I can't seem to find this.  I know there was some form of FAQ provided shortly after I gained access to the Moderator Tools, but I am having trouble locating it again.

Could someone provide a link?  Also, if the link is featured in some part of the website that I've missed, could you point me to that as well?

(As a comparison for clarity, instead of just finding out about "Start->Run, appwiz.cpl", I'd also like to know I could go to "Start->Settings->Control Panel->Add/Remove Programs")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the main site click on your reputation score at the top of the page (yes, it's a link!).  This takes you to the [privilege page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/privileges), where you can click on the [moderator tools link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) on the right to view the FAQ for that..

Comment: Wow... that's kind of an odd place for it.  One would think they'd have a link somewhere within the tools themselves.  Thanks!